# REST update fail, REST insert work

Tags: rest, update, insert

I have this strange issue. I have opened up REST requests using a read only user in a sandbox, all work fine. The request can post an insert in cases and send an update to changes status etc. I then made a change set and moved this to another sandbox (staging for tests), now the insert request still work fine but the updates fail with the following message:

> simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed
> request
> https://xxx--name.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/case/5007Y00000HkSJ2QAN.
> Response content: [{'message': 'entity type cannot be updated: Case',
> 'errorCode': 'CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY', 'fields': []}]

The working insert json looks like this:

```
{
   "RecordTypeId":"0127Y000001yDkdQAE",
   "OPS_IM_record_Id__c":"OPS-6163",
   "Subject":"Grafana Platform uptime alert",
   "Description":"Platform is down for more than 15m",
   "Customer_Reference__c":"None",
   "Environment__c":"Production system",
   "Type":"Infra",
   "Details__c":"",
   "Reference__c":"Check Runbook|https://xxx.zzz.net/wiki/search?text=Uptime&spaces=DEV&labels=kb-how-to-article,runbook,xaas&type=page&title=true",
   "Severity__c":"critical",
   "Status":"NEW",
   "Event_Source__c":"Grafana",
   "Platform__c":"PaaS"
}
```

and the non working update json look like this:

```
{
   "Status":"RESOLVED",
   "Resolved_By__c":"0052p000009GXTPAA4",
   "Event_AutoResolved__c" : true
}
```

When googling this all I find is that is should be a permission issue in the user's profile but the status field is available (required) in the insert request and the two other fields are editable and visible for the user and profile.

I have verified the profile and can't spot any differences between the two sandboxes.

Any ideas?

//Daniel

Comment: What HTTP Error code is returned with your response? As per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/errorcodes.htm

Comment: You are using a Read Only profile?  if so, behavior is changing; see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000355656&type=1&mode=1